# Specifing Timezone in Quartz Jobs XML (Cron Trigger)

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to define a Cron Trigger for a job in Quartz.NET 2.0

I see that the XML file format now supports `<time-zone>` element.

What format should I use for the time zone? I couldn't find any reference for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quartz uses the following code to resolve time zone:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = timezoneString != null ? 
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneString) : null;
```

From `XMLSchedulingDataProcessor` class, see [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx). The same functionality in Java version of Quartz scheduler uses:

```
TimeZone tz = timezoneString == null ? 
  null : TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would *expect* it to be the ID returned by [`TimeZoneInfo.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx). I can't find any evidence for that at the moment (although I'm going to browse the source when I can, ideally on a better network connection...) but that would be the first thing I'd try.

(EDIT: Yes, that's what Tomasz's answer confirms. Personally I think it would be nice to support zoneinfo IDs, but hey... maybe one day Quartz will integrate with [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) :)